# ORDER month TABLE by current month

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to order months with the current month in final position.

I have a subquery that returns this:

```
+-----+-----------+
| one | monthname |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   |   Jan     |
| 2   |   Feb     |
| 3   |   Mar     |
| 4   |   Apr     |
| ... |   ...     |
+-----+-----------+
```

Then I want to order this to get the current month (`MONTH(NOW())`) as the last value. But I keep getting the default month order.

For example, today, in July (month n°7), I would like to have:

```
+-----+-----------+
| one | monthname |
+-----+-----------+
|  8  |   Aug     |
|  9  |   Sep     |
| 10  |   Oct     |
| 11  |   Nov     |
| 12  |   Dec     |
|  1  |   Jan     |
|  2  |   Feb     |
|  3  |   Mar     |
|  4  |   Apr     |
|  5  |   Mei     |
|  6  |   Jun     |
|  7  |   Jul     |
+-----+-----------+
```

Is it possible to do in an SQL query? If so, what is the best way to proceed?

### Edit

My current query is the following

```
SELECT `months`,
IFNULL(case_result.Total_rows,0) results 
FROM 
(SELECT `one`,`monthname` AS months FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS `one`, 'JANUARY' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 2 AS `one`,'FEBURARY' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 3 AS `one`, 'MARCH' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 4 AS `one`, 'APRIL' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 5 AS `one`, 'MAY' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 6 AS `one`,'JUNE' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 7 AS `one`,'JULY' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 8 AS `one`, 'AUGUST' AS `monthname`
UNION SELECT 9 AS `one`, 'SEPTEMBER' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 10 AS `one`, 'OCTOBER' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 11 AS `one`, 'NOVEMBER' AS `monthname` 
UNION SELECT 12 AS `one`, 'DECEMBER' AS `monthname` order by ) AS month_table) tempmonths LEFT JOIN (SELECT MONTH(date_surgery) AS `month`, COUNT(id_cases) AS Total_Rows 
FROM cases 
WHERE date_surgery BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND NOW()
AND cases.name = 'Bone Tumor'
GROUP BY MONTH(`date_surgery`)) AS case_result ON tempmonths.one = case_result.month
```

But the part that I need to order is this subquery

```
SELECT 1 AS `one`, 'JANUARY' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 2 AS `one`,'FEBURARY' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 3 AS `one`, 'MARCH' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 4 AS `one`, 'APRIL' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 5 AS `one`, 'MAY' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 6 AS `one`,'JUNE' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 7 AS `one`,'JULY' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 8 AS `one`, 'AUGUST' AS `monthname`
    UNION SELECT 9 AS `one`, 'SEPTEMBER' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 10 AS `one`, 'OCTOBER' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 11 AS `one`, 'NOVEMBER' AS `monthname` 
    UNION SELECT 12 AS `one`, 'DECEMBER' AS `monthname` order by ...
```

Comment: post your current query and data sample, or it would be even better if you provide an sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Alex I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `one` is the name of the column that has the month number, just add this to your `select` statement:

```
order by (one+11-month(now)) % 12
```

That expression will be 11 for the current month, and for all other months it will be less because of the modulo operator (`%`).